# Is there a clean way to get attributes from appsettings.json, and use them inside a class attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

The idea is to allow configure authentication values in appsettings (asp.net.core), and to use an authorization attribute so that a controller gets automatic authentication and it is configurable from appsettings.

The dirty way would be using a static variable, but I believe there is a better way that I don't get because of my lack of knowledge about the framework.

```
[AuthorizeAttribute("some value from appsettings")]
class Controller : ApiController
```

Comment: A class attribute is *metadata/annotations* generated by the *compiler*. They are used as annotations/metadata used by other classes like middleware, they don't do something by themselves. `Authorize` for example, doesn't check the caller's credentials. It's the authorization middleware that checks which controllers/actions have that attribute and asks for credentials when they are called

Comment: It does look a little bit like an X/Y problem - just define a Claim (Role) per controller. That shouldn't need to be configurable.

Comment: What are trying to do? What you ask is already providec by ASP.NET Core itself. Authorization is described in the documentation extensively and covered in courses and tutorials. All authorization tutorials show how to load settings from json files, environment variables etc, how to configure *Facebook* or Google authentication, how to work with other kinds of claims etc

Comment: Claims/Policies can cover a lot of things, not just roles. Do you want to allow access by admins only if they login after midnight on a full moon, from a certain IP range? You can configure that. Use two-factor authentication? Already implemented

Comment: Need just basic authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to set the appsetting values dynamically to your attribute.

I suggest you should go for policy based authorization like

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Policy1", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("YourRoleName"));
    });
```

In the above code you can replace the "YourRoleName" from the appsetting easily.

In your action, you can configure the policy like following.

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "Policy1")]
```

To read more about authorization policy you can check [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2)